# Transform tables when screen size changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 columns of data, each with 2 rows inside. I would like to make to transform 3x2 table into 1x6 table, when the width of the screen is less than some value. Any idea how to achieve this?

My column has the following structure:

```
<div class="one-third animate_afl">
  <div class="w-iconbox custom_img iconpos_left size_big type_default color_primary">
    <div class="w-iconbox-link" >
      <div class="w-iconbox-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-"></i>
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/04/9-over.png" alt="">    
      </div>
      <h4 class="w-iconbox-title">Title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="w-iconbox-text">
      <p>Paragraph text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="g-hr type_invisible">
    <span class="g-hr-h">
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="w-iconbox custom_img iconpos_left size_big type_default color_primary">
    <div class="w-iconbox-link">
      <div class="w-iconbox-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-"></i>
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/04/modul1-over.png" alt="">   
      </div>
      <h4 class="w-iconbox-title">Title 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="w-iconbox-text">
      <p>Paragraph text 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-iconbox custom_img iconpos_left size_big type_default color_primary">
    <div class="w-iconbox-text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use something like Bootstrap.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many approaches in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=responsive+table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would surely involve CSS media queries, which allow you to do this very thing. You can even set multiple break-widths where your css can change for each width you want, as many as you want.